# In java, how can I create an array inside an array of different data types

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, types

```
String [] cabin_names={"Hetty","Poppy","Blus Skies","Bay View",
                               "Happy Days","Summer Joy","Walkers' Rest",
                               "Bertie","Green Forest Lodge","Coppice Lodge"}; 

int[] cabin_capacity={4,4,4,6,6,6,8,8,10,10};

double[] cabin_peak={400.00,400.00,500.00,650.00,695.00,800.00,950.00,
                             1050.00,1200.00,1500.00};

double[] cabin_offpeak={250.00,250.00,350.00,500.00,550.00,600.00,750.00,
                                850.00,950.00,1150.00};
```

I've tried to put all these arrays into one array, but they're all different data types.

```
float[][] array_of_all_cabin_deets={cabin_names,cabin_capacity,cabin_peak,cabin_offpeak};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that by specifying the types of the arrays, one solution can be is to create a class called `Cabin`

```
public class Cabin {
    private String name;
    private int capacity;
    private double peak;
    private double offBeak;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public double getPeak() {
        return peak;
    }

    public void setPeak(double peak) {
        this.peak = peak;
    }

    public double getOffBeak() {
        return offBeak;
    }

    public void setOffBeak(double offBeak) {
        this.offBeak = offBeak;
    }
}
```

And then create an array of `Cabin`

```
    Cabin[] cabins = new Cabin[3];
    Cabin cabin = new Cabin();
    cabin.setName("Hetty");
    cabin.setPeak(4);
    cabin.setOffBeak(250.00);
    cabins[0] = cabin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating the outer array of type Object

```
        Object[] genericArray = {cabin_names, cabin_capacity, cabin_peak, cabin_offpeak};
```

Comment: How is that useful? How would you access the fields in the individual arrays given the outer `genericArray` ?

Comment: We will have to type cast to access each field of the array.